# setting node size in gephi 0.82

Tags: gephi

I'm trying to draw a graph but i can't understand how to set the node size through the UI.

I've seen other graphs here (http://dhs.stanford.edu/dh/gephi/dhstanford2.html) that manage to do that.

I couldn't see how this is done. In comparison, inNodeXL there is column called Size, so it's not that difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the 'how do resize the nodes' is a question i get the most probably because, the 'resize node' icon is not very iconic. 
Here is a screen shot of where you can find it as it is super hard to miss.

[image]

Comment: For newer versions like 0.9.1 see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239873/change-node-size-gephi-0-9-1

Answer (score 3):

There is a "size" icon towards the bottom left of the main graph window in the GUI. If you *right click* on this icon, you will be able to set the default size for your nodes. Then, *left clicking* on this same icon will apply this default size to all nodes.

Comment: is there a way of setting the size of each node according to some parameter?

Comment: Yes, you'd use the ranking panel for that, making sure you select the "size ranking" mode (by clicking on the "red diamond kind-of-shape" icon within the ranking panel). There, you can choose a numerical attribute that will determine the size of your nodes.