# Change node size gephi 0.9.1

Tags: gephi

I have looked everywhere but I don't seem to able to get the answer for the latest version of Gephi (0.9.1).
All  I want to do is change the node size based on its in-degree for all the nodes on the graph. This used to be something I could do with the ranking tool but since this has been merged into the 'Appearance' tab I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bit late but even if you have found it, it might help someone else. Check the highlighted areas

[image]

Comment: How is it possible to add a new attribute to this list, like a column in the node file? When I open available examples in Gephi one of them has such attributes, but the two others do not have.

Comment: Well it really depends on the attribute. Attributes like _In-degree_, _Centrality measures_, _PageRank_, etc. are produced only after you run the corresponding command from the **Statistics** panel. If you need a custom attribute you need to go to the **Data laboratory** and run _Add column_. This allows you to enter values (numeric or categorical) for your custom attribute

Answer (score 1):

Weird but works: In Overview, in the Appearance tab, click on the mini icon for color (*not* for size). Diagonally down to the left, you should see a little icon of some colored blocks. If you mouse over them, the pop-up says,"Switch to ranking". Click that. Then above toe the right, click on the icon for size instead of color this time. Now when you select to modify the node appearance by attribute, it should let you do it by your custom column.

See https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1479, where rbsam wrote in 2016, "On Appearence/Attributes by color you can set the attribute to Partitioning to Ranking on the botton left of the window. If the attribute is set to Partitioning it will not appear on Size attribute. If it is set to Ranking it will appear on Size attribute."